# Download many csv files from website and convert into one file

Tags: python-3.x, url, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I want to download a stock prices from the website. Unfortunately I have an issue with this. I wrote a code but I can get data only from the first company. My target is to get all data for all companies (something around 800). Stock prices need only for last month

Below you can find a code:

```
import urllib.request
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

##############################################################################
#getting tickers and names of companies

url = 'http://infostrefa.com/infostrefa/pl/spolki'

html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]

tickers = df["Ticker"].values
names_of_company = df["Nazwa giełdowa"].values

#tickers will be useful to put them into a website address
tickers = list(tickers)
names_of_company = list(names_of_company)

##############################################################################

for name in names_of_company: 
    url2 = 'http://infostrefa.com/infostrefa/pl/profile/675,{}/historical-quotations/xlsx?dateFrom=2018-07-24&dateTo=2018-08-24'

    page2 = requests.get(url2)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page2.content,'lxml')

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url2, 'output.csv')
```

I will be a grateful for any advice. Thanks for All !

Comment: You aren't using `name` in `url2` to change a name - looks like you've got the `{}` in there for it... but you never use `.format` on it...

Comment: but I am not sure how to use it. Do you have perhaps a guide or tutorial how I could do that ?

Comment: The official python documentation explains "string formatting" very well...